# Is there a way to have a get only (no set) in a typescript interface?

Tags: interface, typescript

I have a case where I want to have just a get in the interface, no set. Is there a way to do that?

If not, we can implement a set and throw an exception if it is called. But it's cleaner if we can have just a get.

At present I have:

```
export interface IElement {
    type : TYPE;
}

export class Element implements IElement {

    public get type () : TYPE {
        return TYPE.UNDEFINED;
    }

    public set type (type : TYPE) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I would like to have my interface & class be:

```
export class Element implements IElement {

    public get type () : TYPE {
        return TYPE.UNDEFINED;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about sharing some code to see if we can understand what you mean?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - I just added a sample. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is preventing you from implementing what you say you want to implement? I cannot see what is your impediment to achieve that.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo the exceptions find errors at runtime. If there is no set it finds it at compile time. Much safer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript interfaces cannot currently define a property as read-only. If it's important to prevent, you'll need to throw an exception/error at runtime to prevent sets within the setter for the property.

The compiler doesn't require that you implement the `get` and a `set` though. You can just implement the `get` for example. However, at runtime, it won't be caught.